# OCR SDK to convert Arabic and English text from scanned cards

Tags: gratis, c#, .net, ocr, sdk

Which is the good yet economical (or free) OCR SDK to convert Arabic and English text from scanned card images?

**Kind of Application**
OCR SDK (Software Development Kit)

**Platform**
The SDK should be consumable from within the .NET framework

**Features Required**
Character Recognition in Arabic and English

**Budget**
Not more than 1,000 USD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [LEADTOOLS OCR SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/professional-arabic-ocr). This is a commercial library with [OCR support for Arabic](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/to/leadtools.topics.forms.ocr~fo.topics.ocrlanguagesandspellchecking.html). You try the SDK for free from the [LEADTOOLS main site](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main). The evaluation includes full demo applications and code.

**Kind of Application**: Commercial OCR SDK.

**Platform**: .NET 4.5.+ Yes. (Also supports older .NET framework versions)

**Features Required**: Includes support for over 40 languages including Arabic and English as requested.

Using the Main OCR demo you can test the Arabic OCR support using your scanned images. See sample image below:

[image]

LEADTOOLS also has a [Scanning API](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/twain) if you need to incorporate this process into the OCR recognition.

Comment: This product is not gratis

Answer (score 0):

I have found these two:

1. [CharlesW Tesseract (.NET Wrapper)](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract)
   This is an open-source
2. [RasterEdge](http://www.rasteredge.com/)
   Based on Tesseract also. But costs around 600-800 USD